# .slice and .wrapall

Tags: jquery, slice, wrapall

I'm using a bit of code suggested by a member on stackoverflow and adapted by me to wrap every 3 list items as part of a mega menu. The code is:

```
var lis = $("ul > li");
for(var i = 0; i < ls.length; i+=3) {
  lis.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
}
```

Unfortunately this will grab child li's from the next parent menu to fill up the 'quota' of 3 li's in a div. This is of course massively messing up my menus. <del>For an example please visit here.</del>

Does anyone have any suggestion how I could fix this up?

Comment: What if you remove the `>` from `ul > li`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is your selector. Since `sizzle` works right to left, it will just query all `LI elements` which have an `UL element` as direct parent (which usually, is always the case).

So, seperate your `ULs`.

```
$('ul').each(function(){
   var $lis = $(this).children('li');
   for(var i = 0, len = $lis.length; i < len; i+=3){          
     $lis.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Andy - apologies but I'm very new to jQuery. I think I understand the logic behind what you're saying but unfortuantley I'm unable to get the code snippet you sent working on the demo I included above... Also would this not end up wrapping every 3 li's on a page? Would it be better to specify ul.list-content as the the ul?

thanks for any advice

Comment: hmmn - sorry still no joy with the code above. Does it work for you?

Comment: @csbourne: well I'm fooling around at http://www.jsfiddle.net/cbnFX/
It at least does what I'm expecting :) But I don't have that plugin available there.

Comment: sorry I had a small error in my code. You're a life saver - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried applying it withe the use of the class as ht selector like this?

```
var lis = $("ul.list-content > li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=3) {
  lis.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
}
```

But if you did not know, I'm warning you that you are breaking the dom.. you are putting div on ul which is not good.. ;)